# The word "InnerTube" in a different context

Tags: meaning-in-context, translation, slang, formal-language, informal-language

I´m translating a subtitle of a movie but I have not understood this sentence:
" The things these kids post out on them InnerTube, ohhh boy I do not get that"

What is the meaning of "Innertube" in this context?
What is the meaning of " post out" in this context?

Well, It's a movie called " Ghoster" It was released recently. I also guessed That the person had replaced the word " innertube" to "youtube". More about the context: the main characters were going to buy some paints and wood stuff and when they got into the store, the two old man sellers ( or owners) are speaking. ( probably complaining about this new generation of kids.)

Comment: You need to include more context and cite your source. This is nonstandard English (presumably replacing "YouTube" with "InnerTube", among other issues), and it's hard for us to determine whether the subtitler made an error, whether the speaker made an error, whether the speaker was being facetious, etc.

Comment: Well, It's a movie called " Ghoster" It was released recently. I also guessed That the person had replaced the word " innertube" to "youtube". More about the context: the main characters were going to buy some paints and wood stuff and when they got into the store, the two old man sellers ( or owners) are speaking. ( probably complaining about this new generation of kids.)

Answer (score 2):

The old men are vaguely aware of internet culture but do not know the names of popular services.  They have heard of thing on the internet called "{something}tube" but can't remember clearly what it is called. They guess it is "InnerTube". Similarly "post out" is the old guy trying to use internet terminology, but getting it wrong.

It is just the character getting the words wrong because the character is ignorant of internet culture.

> These kids go and post out garbage on "innertube" and "Yahboo" and "bookface". We didn't do that in our day.

Comment: Thanks in a million.